# En un Input, ¿cómo volver a seleccionar el mismo fichero, y que se active el evento change?

Tags: javascript, html5

Como sabéis un elemento HTML input pasa el/los ficheros seleccionados a través de su evento **change**. Pero imaginaros que un usuario selecciona un fichero, después lo borra (de la aplicación, no del disco duro) accidentalmente y quiere volver a seleccionar el mismo fichero. En el segundo intento el evento **change** no se dispara, porque el navegador no detecta ningún cambio (se ha seleccionado el mismo fichero) entonces ¿cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

A primera vista se me ocurre actualizar el navegador con F5, pero esto requiere salir y volver a entrar de la aplicación, y no me acaba de convencer.

Este sería el código básico para un input:

```
input.addEventListener('change', recogerSeleccionados);

function recogerSeleccionados(){
    var listaFicheros = this.files;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontré pronto la solución y es fácil, se trata de iniciar el valor del **Input**, añadiendo un controlador del evento **click**. El código quedaría así:

```
input.addEventListener('click', iniciarInput);     
input.addEventListener('change', recogerSeleccionados);    

function iniciarInput(){
    this.value = "";
}

function recogerSeleccionados(){
    var listaFicheros = this.files;
}
```